# How to iterate particular value like "card-type": only using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
[
    {
        "card-type": "MAST",
        "card-number": "5123456789012346"
    },
    {
        "card-type": "MAST",
        "card-number": "4444333322221111"
    },      
    {
        "type": "CC_NAME",
        "value": "URP Installments"
    },
    {
        "type": "CC_CVV",
        "value": "123"
    },
    {
        "type": "CC_ADDRESS",
        "value": "URP Dubahi"
    },
    {
        "type": "CC_POSTAL_CODE",
        "value": "201301"
    },
    {
        "type": "CC_CITY",
        "value": "Delhi"
    },
    {
        "type": "CC_STATE",
        "value": "Uttar Pradesh"
    }
]
```

Comment: How i can iterate only Card-type and card number only

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+iterate+key+begins+with+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Do you want like this? data.filter((d) => { return d["card-type"] && d["card-number"] }) Please add more information of your question.

Comment: Please make a minimal effort regarding your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `hasOwnProperty` in this way:

```js
const input = [
    {
        "card-type": "MAST",
        "card-number": "5123456789012346"
    },
    {
        "card-type": "MAST",
        "card-number": "4444333322221111"
    },      
    {
        "type": "CC_NAME",
        "value": "URP Installments"
    },
    {
        "type": "CC_CVV",
        "value": "123"
    },
    {
        "type": "CC_ADDRESS",
        "value": "URP Dubahi"
    },
    {
        "type": "CC_POSTAL_CODE",
        "value": "201301"
    },
    {
        "type": "CC_CITY",
        "value": "Delhi"
    },
    {
        "type": "CC_STATE",
        "value": "Uttar Pradesh"
    }
];

input.forEach((obj) => {
   if(obj.hasOwnProperty("card-type")) {
      console.log(obj);
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

filter and [String.startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

```js
const list = [ { "card-type": "MAST", "card-number": "5123456789012346" }, { "card-type": "MAST", "card-number": "4444333322221111" }, { "type": "CC_NAME", "value": "URP Installments" }, { "type": "CC_CVV", "value": "123" }, { "type": "CC_ADDRESS", "value": "URP Dubahi" }, { "type": "CC_POSTAL_CODE", "value": "201301" }, { "type": "CC_CITY", "value": "Delhi" }, { "type": "CC_STATE", "value": "Uttar Pradesh" } ];

console.log(
   list.filter(item => Object.keys(item).filter(key => key.startsWith("card-")).length>0)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another choice for you

```js
var datas = [
    {
        "card-type": "MAST",
        "card-number": "5123456789012346"
    },
    {
        "card-type": "MAST",
        "card-number": "4444333322221111"
    },      
    {
        "type": "CC_NAME",
        "value": "URP Installments"
    },
    {
        "type": "CC_CVV",
        "value": "123"
    },
    {
        "type": "CC_ADDRESS",
        "value": "URP Dubahi"
    },
    {
        "type": "CC_POSTAL_CODE",
        "value": "201301"
    },
    {
        "type": "CC_CITY",
        "value": "Delhi"
    },
    {
        "type": "CC_STATE",
        "value": "Uttar Pradesh"
    }
];

datas.forEach(d=>{
  if(!!d["card-type"] && !!d["card-number"]){
    console.log(d);
  }
});
```